# Is it possible to simplify error throwing for a combined IF statement?

Tags: java, error-handling

So say I have an `if` statement like `if (bool1 && bool2) {}`.
I want to display different error messages depending on which of these booleans failed. Normally I'd do something like:

```
if (bool1) {
    if (bool2) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // throw error for bool2 failing
    }
} else {
    // throw error for bool1 failing
}
```

Now I only know for sure that `bool1` failed, but `bool2` might be bad as well. Therefor, I'd use something like:

```
if (bool1 && bool2) {
    // do something
} else {
    if (!bool1) {
        // throw error for bool1 failing
    }
    if (!bool2) {
        // throw error for bool2 failing
    }
    ...
}
```

However, this can get very long if there are a lot of variables to check, and especially if you want to display different errors if multiple variables fail.

```
// continuing on the dots of the above code block
if (!bool1 && !bool2) {
    // throw error for both failing
}
```

Is there a more effective method for doing this?

---

Edit: Because all given answers are viable, and which is better is subjective, I'm not going to accept any as 'the' answer. Be sure to pick the method/answer that works best for your own needs.
Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Can't you just give two error messages (one for `bool1` and one for `bool2`)? If you want to throw that with an exception just use an if statement with `!bool1 || !bool2` and in there check both and append the messages to a string and then use that for your exception?

Comment: Maybe you could add all your boolx to a Enum and use a try-catch?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of is to **not** nest your `if` statements. Instead, I would check every error condition independently and accumulate the error messages in a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder errorMsg = new StringBuilder();

if (!bool1) {
    errorMsg.append("bool1 condition failed\n");
}

if (!bool2) {
    errorMsg.append("bool2 condition failed\n");
}

if (!bool3) {
    errorMsg.append("bool3 condition failed\n");
}

// etc

if (errorMsg.length() > 0) {
    throw new SomeException(errorMsg.toString());
}

// safely execute your code here
```

Check the useful [`StringBuilder` class docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me what is your scenario, but maybe I would approach your problem in this way (similar to DAB's answer):

```
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(!bool1){
        errors.add("Error message 1");
    }

    if (!bool2) {
        errors.add("Error message 2");
    }

    // other errors

    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        throw new Exception(buildErrorsMessage(errors));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that, as far as I know. The way to do this more effectively is to restructure your code, so you do not need to nest if-clauses too deeply.

Comment: How would you restructure the second code block I gave as an example?
Especially when checking for lots of individual values and combinations, the if statements don't really nest too deep, but it's just a lot of them in a list.

Comment: That really depends on what you're doing. I had some cases where it was necessary to check lots of booleans, but then I usually did not have to throw exceptions. In many cases, it would make sense to delegate to a method or even a handler class at some point, but that really depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Wha dont you reverse your if ?

```
if(!bool1)
{
    if(!bool2)
    {
        error both
    }
    error bool1
}
else if(!bool2)
{
     error 2
}
else
  do somthing
```

Comment: Interesting thinking, but that would be very content specific to when this would be better. I'll keep it in mind though, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would normally do it...

```
    String error=null;

    if( a )
    {
        error="Error a";
    }
    else if( b )
    {
        error="Error b";
    }
    else if( c )
    {
        error="Error c";
    }

    if( error!=null )
    {
        throw new Exception(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
String error=null;
if(!bool)
    error="Something";
else if(!bool2)
    error="Other message";
else if(!bool3) 
    error="failed??";

// ...
if(error!=null) {
   throw new Exception(error);
}
```

If you need to throw different types of exceptions, you can have error be of type Exception, instead of string, and then create the exception in the if(!bool1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of booleans that should all be in one state you could throw them in an array and see if the array contains the opposite state. You can use a map if you need to keep track of the variables names for the error message. When generating the error message you can loop over the map and check each value.

```
package com.idfbins.questions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class maptest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Boolean> maparini = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        maparini.put("variable1", true);
        maparini.put("variable2", true);
        maparini.put("variable3", true);
        maparini.put("variable4", true);
        maparini.put("variable5", true);

        System.out.println("All are true? " + allAreTrue(maparini));
        System.out.println("All are false? " + allAreFalse(maparini));
        System.out.println("Errors for all true: ");
        errorsForTrue(maparini);
        System.out.println("Errors for all false: ");
        errorsForFalse(maparini);

    }

    public static boolean allAreTrue(Map<String, Boolean> maparini){
        return !maparini.containsValue(false);
    }

    public static boolean allAreFalse(Map<String, Boolean> maparini){
        return !maparini.containsValue(true);
    }

    public static void errorsForFalse(Map<String, Boolean> maparini){
        for(Entry<String, Boolean> mapariniEntry : maparini.entrySet()){
            if(mapariniEntry.getValue()){
                System.out.println(mapariniEntry.getKey() + " was true!");
                //You can construct a string to throw in an exception here
            }
        }
    }

    public static void errorsForTrue(Map<String, Boolean> maparini){
        for(Entry<String, Boolean> mapariniEntry : maparini.entrySet()){
            if(!mapariniEntry.getValue()){
                System.out.println(mapariniEntry.getKey() + " was false!");
                //You can construct a string to throw in an exception here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could even add an expected value to the map so that you add an entry like `maparini.put("Variable name", booleanVariable, expectedBooleanValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void throwIf(boolean condition, Supplier<T> e) throws T {
    if(condition) throw e.get();
}
```

```
throwIf(!bool1 && !bool2, () -> new Exception("big oops"));
throwIf(!bool1, MyException::new);
throwIf(!bool2, () -> new Exception("oops"));
throwIf(!bool3, Error::new);

// do something
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (!bool1 && !bool2) {
        // throw error for bool1 && bool2 failing
    } else if (!bool1) {
        // throw error for bool1 failing
    } else {
        // throw error for bool2 failing
    }
```